# VSIX doesn't register itself to Help/About window in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, visual-studio-sdk

I'm trying to develop a VS extension using the Visual Adornment project template.

The extension is working on the experimental instance of VS (it simply adds a text layer on the editor window), but now I'm trying to add 2 features, with no luck:

- Help/About entry for the extension
- Settings page for some basic configurations

So I started to study some other extension to understand how they do that, taking as example this from Phil Haack [Encourage](https://github.com/Haacked/Encourage).

No way I can get it to work. I created a class that inherits from Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package and I've decorated it with all the needed attribute to have the Help/About entry, without any success.

```
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true)]
[ComVisible(true)]
[InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "1.0", IconResourceID = 400)]
[Guid("665d2c8c-0d47-42b6-ae34-e1db4ac2ed0f")]
public sealed class MyPackage : Package
{
    public MyPackage()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Entering constructor for: {0}", this.ToString()));
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

        Debug.WriteLine("Initialize MyPackage");
    }
}
```

Not only the package is not registering, but the debug lines are not written at all, I cannot even step in with the debugger.

I took a look around the web, and any article I found sounds like [this](http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0166/) one, even following any single step, my package is not registering itself **BUT**, and it is the strange thing, the viewport adornment it's working as expected...

**UPDATE:**

I can add some details: it seems that during the build the .pkgdef file is not created at all in the debug folder, and it's not added to the VSIX file (if I open it with 7zip there's no .pkgdef)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No way I can get it to work. I created a class that inherits from Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package and I've decorated it with all the needed attribute to have the Help/About entry, without any success.

I didn't understand that part quite. You're supposed to use Visual Studio "project template" for "Visual Studio packages". That will create all the stuff necessary to build `VSIX` file. Start with that, if you  **already** haven't.

By default, Visual Studio extensions(>=2013) don't load automatically. This took me few hours of debugging, but you're supposed to decorate your package with an attribute if you'd like to load when Visual Studio starts up. Alternatively, there's an option to load your VSPackage once a solution is loaded.

This is a peek of my package definition:

```
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true)]
[InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "1.0", IconResourceID = 400)]
[Guid(Guids.GuidMyStudioPackageString)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids.NoSolution)]
[ProvideMenuResource("Menus.ctmenu", 1)]

public sealed class MyPackage : CommonPackage
```

Notice the `[ProvideAutoLoad(...)]` option. It says that load the package once visual studio starts.

Comment: You're right, I came up with the same solution. I was using the "VSIX Project", manually adding all the stuffs, not the "Visual Studio Package" template that already adds the Package class and all the other thing. Said that is anyway strange that configuring manually a project to expose a package doesn't work at all, I cannot understand what is the difference between the preconfigured template and my previous project... Thanks anyway for confirming it!

Comment: To be clear: it's the fact you used a different template that meant the pkgdef is being generated. The PackageAutoLoad is not necessary here, and in fact is highly discouraged because of the performance impact.